# Is it possible to run different nVidia card models in SLI?

Tags: sli

It it possible to SLI an 8800GT with a 260GT? If not, do the newest models support mixing models in SLI?

Comment: What? Can you please elaborate on your question a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit-

I was wrong, just done a bit more research and tried it here on a spare machine and some stock cards I have on the shelf.

If you try multiple cards from the same generation - 7x series, 8x series etc, it works at the speed of the slower device.

If you try multiple cards from different generations - a 7x series with a 8x series, once it worked but the second card was simply dead and displayed nothing, in a different configuration, it just won't display anything on either cards.

I can confirm that nothing is broken and both cards work fine, so you have nothing to loose by trying it, however based on what I have just seen, it will only work if you use two from the same generation.

Comment: I've always seen that the GPU core has to be the same for SLI, but vRAM could be different and only the smallest common amount would be used. Do you have a link to where two completely different models can be mixed in SLI?

Comment: @MarkM, you are correct - +1, just edited my answer after testing.

Comment: That's too bad, I haven't been keeping up on SLI, I have hoping they had finally introduced hybrid SLI like ATI has with crossfire.