# PCIe Video Card has a connector on top

Tags: video, graphics-card, computer-building, pci-express

I have an 8500GT XFX 512MB Video card(like the picture) and I noticed that it had an interesting looking connector at the top of it. At first I didn't really take it into much though, until the other day I saw another video card that had the same little port on the top. I was hoping that you could tell me what it was and what it is used for.

[image]

Comment: Its to support SLI

Comment: I thought it was there to allow you to attach an additional D-SUB port?

Comment: @Ramhound Very Interesting, After reading what SLI was I am curious, do the two video cards have to be the same, or can they be different?

Comment: Similar question(s) regarding SLI are already on here. IE: http://superuser.com/questions/370077/how-to-sli-a-system-need-expert-guide, http://superuser.com/questions/52175/is-it-possible-to-run-different-nvidia-card-models-in-sli?rq=1, etc.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Link_Interface

Comment: @JVarhol - Additional research on SLI will answer that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking at is an SLI connector. SLI is a technology by which multiple Nvidia GPUs can be used in unison to provide better performance than a single GPU would.

Along with better performance, SLI provides other benefits. In an SLI configuration, a second GPU can be used in a game supporting [PhysX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhysX) as a PhysX processor, and SLI supports [SLI Antialiasing](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/faq#d1).

Both AMD and Nvidia provide similar technologies on their cards. [SLI](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/technology) is the Nvidia specific technology that enables this function, while [Crossfire](http://sites.amd.com/us/game/technology/Pages/crossfirex.aspx) is a similar technology available on select AMD cards.

Supported SLI GPUs can be found [here](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/supported-gpus). For SLI you will need two (or more) of the same GPU, a compatible motherboard, and an SLI bridge like the one pictured below:

[image: Nvidia SLI]

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense, I have a motherboard that I got a month or so ago that has one of these connectors with it but nothing to hint at what it is.

Comment: Using a secondary GPU for PhysX is not related to SLI, by the way.

Answer (score -1):

For SLI to work, you will need the Bridge Connector, and then I believe the rules are that they have to be the same GPU.  I've done SLI several times, and when I do, I just buy two of the same card to make sure that they are compatible.

I also believe I've read something that nVidia has come up with a way to SLI with cards that are at least in the same family, but not necessarily identical.  It's been a while, so I don't have a solid answer on that, but a little bit of Google'ing or looking on nVidia's website for SLI requirements should get you a quick answer.

Comment: I suggest you research your answer and remove the two "I believe" statements and the "you should google this" otherwise its not really all that helpful of an answer